# How can I switch windows in Vim

Tags: vim, window, buffer

I am using Vim and I am unable to switch to one of my windows by using the default bind keys `<ctrl+w> j`. I have three windows open and the bottom right window is inaccessible. Why is this happening?[image]

Comment: It looks to me like you've opened vim inside a terminal inside vim.  I'm unfamiliar with how terminals work in newer versions of vim, but I suspect that they operate a little differently than regular buffers.

Comment: Just verified @RandyMorris, If vim is opened in a vim :terminal and then split, the <esc><ctrl>w cmds skip the split and jump between the main vim and the :terminal's first window.

Answer (score 10):

`<ctrl> + w + w` works for me.

If you `:sp` or `:vsp` to split a pane, `<ctrl> + w + w` will allow you to navigate between them.

Answer (score 5):

It appears as if you have taken something similar to the following course of action

```
vim <some-file>
:vs <some-other-file>
<C-w> l     // to get to the right window
:term       // to open up a terminal session within right right window
<C-w> j     // to move to the bottom right window (a normal vim window)
:q
vim <file>  // within the terminal inside the right vim window
:sp <file>  // split that window
```

Now it will appear as if you have three vim windows, when in reality, you have four:

- Two outer (the left, and the right terminal session)
- Two within the right window's terminal session

This is quite a precarious position because whether you are in the outer left or right session, the outer *buffer* (not sure if this is the correct word so please correct me if I'm wrong) will always captures the `<C-w>` control character for some reason.

You can see this by looking where the `<C-w>` shows up on the screen when you press it. If I have replicated your environment correctly, it shows up in the bottom right corner **below** the outer *buffer's* right window.

As a workaround to this, instead of using `<C-w>` to proc window navigation, you need to use:

```
:winc j
```

to navigate to the bottom right window.